# ASP.NET Core richtexteditor devexpress blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor, devexpress

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DevExpress.AspNetCore.RichEdit;
using DevExpress.AspNetCore;
using DevExpress.Web.Mvc.UI;
using DevExpress.Blazor.RichEdit;
using System.Runtime;

namespace TextEditor.Pages
{
    public static RichEditBuilder RichEdit(this BuilderFactory factory,
        string name
    );
}
```

I get these errors:

> Error CS1106
> Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class
>
> Error CS0116
> A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
>
> Error CS0501
> '.RichEdit(BuilderFactory, string)' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial    TextEditor

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `public static class RichEditUtils` which then contains this method of yours - you cannot have that method directly in the namespace level...

```
namespace TextEditor.Pages
{
    public static class RichEditUtils
    {
        public static RichEditBuilder RichEdit(this BuilderFactory factory, string name)
        {
            // do something here that ends up returning a "RichEditBuilder" ...
        }
    }
}
```